# Pre/In/Postfix traversal in C including an Array

Tags: c, preorder

I would like to implement functions where I perform a pre, in and postorder traversal of an existing binary tree.

these traversals should then be displayed by a predefined test function

here's what i got so far for the preorder traversal

```
uint64_t i = 0;
int *binarytree_prefix(binarytree *tree) {
    uint64_t *prefixArray = malloc(inputArrayLength_helper * sizeof(uint64_t));

    prefixArray[i] = tree->value;
    i++;
    if (tree->left != NULL) {
        return (binarytree_prefix(tree->left));
    }

    if (tree->right != NULL) {
        return (binarytree_prefix(tree->right));
    }
}
```

what I thought about it that it would insert the value of the current node into the array and then increent the position within the array and do a recursion on the left and then the right tree
however this does not work. 
i hope someone is able to help me to make it running

What i did was a depth first search with a preorder traversal and then included the array to fill it with the current value

test function within main:

```
int *prefixArray = bintree_prefix(tree);

printf("Prefix notation : ");
for(uint64_t i = 0; i < inputArrayLength; i++) {
    printf(" %d", prefixArray[i]);
}
printf("\n");

free(prefixArray);
```

Comment: Try it; and then ask a specific question about a problem you encountered.

Comment: tried it, programm segfaults, so in the end it does not give back the preorder traversal, added test function

Comment: segfault in following line: { printf(" %d", prefixArray[i]); }

Comment: OK, so 'i' is probably wrong.  What does your debugger tell you about its value?

Comment: ..or prefixArray is wrong -  what does your debugger tell you about its value?

Comment: Tell you what, YOU do some debugging FFS.

Comment: which one do you mean? in the implemented function by myself or the test function?

Comment: (gdb) p i,$1 = 0//p prefixArray, $2 = (int *) 0x0

Comment: (gdb) p bintree_prefix
$4 = {int *(bintree *)} 0x4009cb <bintree_prefix>

Comment: ok i think i found on huge mistake, the recursion allocates new memory with every new call so that the array gets overwritten all the time.
s there any way to just jump to a specific line as long as the traversal is going on? for example a new function inside the binarytree_prefix function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after a few different variations of the code i finally got the right solution

for those interested

```
int *bintree_prefix(bintree *tree)
{
int *prefixArray = malloc(17*sizeof(uint64_t));
return (bintree_prefix_visited(tree, prefixArray));
}
int bintree_prefix_visited(bintree *tree, int *prefixArray)
{
if (tree!=NULL)
    {
    prefixArray[a]=tree->value;
    a++;
    bintree_prefix_visited(tree->left, prefixArray);
    bintree_prefix_visited(tree->right, prefixArray);
    }
return prefixArray;
}
```

Comment: That is not right. The return type of `bintree_prefix_visited` is `int` while the `return` statement returns `prefixArray`, whose type is `int*`.

Comment: when i change the return type of bintree_prefix_visited to int* then the coompiler gives me an error, however with the given result it gives me a warning though, but compiles fine and the needed result is correct